# Switch the value appearing in Select Tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, html-select

How to switch the value appearing in this select tag example...

If I've selected **Code for Humans** in list the value that will appear is 556, if I've selected **Code for Animals** the value appearing in select box will be 556. How should I do that? Do I need a javascript or something to be add in select tag?

```
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="556">Code for Humans</option>
  <option value="556">Code for Animals</option>
  <option value="556">Code for Elements</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why would you do that? if you want display to be 1 and not "one" then why don't you change the options also?

Comment: It's need  in my web application. For a reason, the text should be appear first to know the Description value.

Comment: Can't you make the `option` text (not `value`) in the format "Code - Description"?

Comment: why not show the description text only and just below the select box, show a label with the code?

Comment: How to do label with code value?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way because this is how select box works.

However you can try putting a text box just above the select box (put the text box without border and select box in a div and make the text box width full with margin and padding enough to make the textbox fit in the select box).

Handle the focus of text to show the dropdown and on selection, show the code in the text box. So, user sees the text box with code and not the selected value.

Demo - jsfiddle.net/5E7DS/

But ofcouse this would not behave exactly like select box. It would be easier and correct also to change the text itself to show the code.

Comment: possible, but if the code must be shown then wouldn't it be easier to put it in the option text itself? (like `556 - Code for Humans`)

Comment: Sad to hear that, I know the select tag composed only of value and text, I thought there would be a way using javascript or something.